# how to get the image size using php

Tags: php

hi guys i am using `<input type='file' name='filett' size='filett'>` and move the file into the temporary location. Just i wants to know how to get the image size using php . i am using `$rect = thegetimagesize("img/flag.jpg");` but if i echo the variable `$rect` it shows the error

Comment: Why does your `size` attribute contain a string? AFAIK it is an old integer attribute to refer to how large you want the input. Some browsers ignore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean the filesize or dimensions?

#### Dimensions

[`getimagesize()`](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) will get a bunch of info about an image. Easiest way to get width and height is to assign it to `list($width, $height)` language construct.

#### Filesize

[`filesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) will get the size of bytes in the file. Divide by 1024 to get kilobytes and so forth.

Answer (score 3):

Use `imagesx()`, `imagesy()`, or `getimagesize()`